# Trying to get QProcess to work with a queue

Tags: python, queue, pyqt5, qprocess, pyside2

I am trying to run several processes with a queue and get the output for all processes using `QProcess` but I am having a couple of issues. I am using a `QSpinBox` to set the max processes to run at the same time and I can get everything working fine in the main thread or if I run the loop with the processes in a `QObject` but I am unable to get it to work properly in a `QThread`.
I know there is no need for using threads with `QProcess` but with the loop I pretty much have no choice. When ran in the main thread it freezes momentarily until the processes start and I'd rather have it run smoother.
I get nothing but errors trying to run the processes in `QThread` unless I use something like `_process.waitForFinished()` but the problem with that is the processes only run one at a time.
Does anyone have any suggestions to get this working properly? I am currently using Pyside2 but an answer for Pyside2 or PyQt5 would be fine. Thanks.

```
import queue
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QProcess, QTextCodec, QThread, Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSpinBox, \
    QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.startBtn = QPushButton('Start', clicked=self.addToQueue)
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox(value=3)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.startBtn)
        self.taskList = ['my.exe -value','my.exe -value','my.exe -value','my.exe -value',
                         'my.exe -value','my.exe -value','my.exe -value','my.exe -value']

    def addToQueue(self):
        for i in self.taskList:
            self.queue.put(i)
        self.sendToThread()

    def sendToThread(self):
        vals = {'max': self.spinBox.value()}
        self.taskThread = TaskThread(self.queue, vals)
        self.taskThread.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

class TaskThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, queue=None, vals=None, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.queue = queue
        self.vals = vals
        self.maxProcs = self.vals.get('max')
        self.procCount = 0

    def run(self):
        self.start_procs()

    def start_procs(self):
        while not self.queue.empty() and self.procCount < self.maxProcs:
            cmd = self.queue.get()
            _process = QProcess(self)
            _process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
            self.codec = QTextCodec.codecForLocale()
            self._decoder_stdout = self.codec.makeDecoder()
            _process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(lambda process=_process: self._ready_read_standard_output(process))
            _process.started.connect(self.procStarted)
            _process.finished.connect(self.procFinished)
            _process.finished.connect(self.decreaseCount)
            _process.finished.connect(self.start_procs)
            _process.start(cmd)
            self.procCount += 1

    def _ready_read_standard_output(self, process):
        self.out = process.readAllStandardOutput()
        self.text = self._decoder_stdout.toUnicode(self.out)
        print(self.text)

    def decreaseCount(self):
        if self.procCount <= 0:
            pass
        else:
            self.procCount -= 1

    def procStarted(self):
        print('started')

    def procFinished(self):
        print('finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(200, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: From what I understand you, you have n tasks and you only want to execute my tasks in an instant of time so if one task is finished, it must be replaced by another one. I am right?. To put it in a numerical example let's say you have 50 tasks and you want to execute a maximum of 6 tasks, then first 6 tasks will be executed and if one of those tasks is finished it should be replaced by another one of the remaining tasks.

Comment: On the other hand let's say that you have set 6 tasks at most and then with the QSlider you change to 4 tasks then should you kill 2 tasks or just not add tasks until you reach the new maximum?

Comment: Sorry, I just seen your reply. I am trying to run multiple tasks async in a queue. So if I have 10 tasks and I set the spinbox to 4 then 4 of the 10 tasks will run and and the new tasks start as the others complete but never having more than the set amount of tasks running at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you launch a process it does not mean that it started because it can have execution problems, so in the first launch it is better to wait for the process to be started or failed to launch the following process, fulfilling the requirements that the number of processes is running is less than the maximum or no longer do tasks or has not started.

On the other hand I have also implemented the task of stopping, which implies that no more tasks will be added but the tasks that were being executed before stopping will continue to be executed.

If you change the maxvalue to a lower value then no more tasks will be thrown until the condition is met.

Considering the above, it is not necessary to use threads

```
import queue
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class TaskManager(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.Signal(str)
    numbersTaskRunningChanged = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TaskManager, self).__init__(parent)
        self._max_task = 1
        self._queue = queue.Queue()
        self._numbers_task_running = 0
        self._running = False

    def setMaxTask(self, max_task):
        self._max_task = max_task
        if self._running:
            self.call_task()

    def maxTask(self):
        return self._max_task

    def appendTask(self, task):
        self._queue.put(task)
        self.call_task()

    def start(self):
        self._running = True
        self.call_task()

    def stop(self):
        self._running = False

    def call_task(self):
        if self._numbers_task_running < self.maxTask() and not self._queue.empty() and self._running:
            cmd = self._queue.get()
            process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
            process.setProcessChannelMode(QtCore.QProcess.MergedChannels)
            process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.on_readyReadStandardOutput)
            process.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
            process.started.connect(self.on_started)
            process.errorOccurred.connect(self.on_errorOccurred)
            process.start(cmd)

    def on_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        codec = QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForLocale()
        decoder_stdout = codec.makeDecoder()
        process = self.sender()
        text = decoder_stdout.toUnicode(process.readAllStandardOutput())
        self.messageChanged.emit(text)

    def on_errorOccurred(self, error):
        process = self.sender()
        print("error: ", error, "-", " ".join([process.program()] + process.arguments()))
        self.call_task()

    def on_finished(self):
        process = self.sender()
        self._numbers_task_running -= 1
        self.numbersTaskRunningChanged.emit(self._numbers_task_running)
        self.call_task()

    def on_started(self):
        process = self.sender()
        print("started: ", " ".join([process.program()] + process.arguments()))
        self._numbers_task_running += 1
        self.numbersTaskRunningChanged.emit(self._numbers_task_running)
        self.call_task()

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        manager = TaskManager(self)
        task_list = # ...
        for task in task_list:
            manager.appendTask(task)

        button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start", clicked=manager.start)
        button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop", clicked=manager.stop)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("0", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        manager.numbersTaskRunningChanged.connect(label.setNum)
        spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        spinBox.valueChanged.connect(manager.setMaxTask)
        spinBox.setValue(3)
        textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        manager.messageChanged.connect(textEdit.append)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(spinBox)
        lay.addWidget(button_start)
        lay.addWidget(button_stop)
        lay.addWidget(label)
        lay.addWidget(textEdit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works well. The main reason I was trying to use a QThread was to avoid the initial lag of the processes being started but it's really no big deal. I am glad your method got rid of the while loop too. I was having trouble getting it to work properly without an extra loop involved. Really appreciate the help!